# What is the covariance of two dependent normal distributed random variables

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-expectation, covariance

Problem is about getting the covariance of two random variables that are not independent: $\operatorname{cov}(\tilde{x}\mid(\tilde{y}=y),\tilde{x})= \text{ ?}$

$$\tilde{x}\sim N(\mu_1,\sigma^2_1)$$

$$\tilde{x}\mid (\tilde{y}=y) \sim N(\mu_2,\sigma^2_2)$$

where $\tilde{y}=\tilde{x}+\tilde{n}$ where $n$ is also normal distributed. So there is a change in both the mean and variance for the conditional distribution.

Now my question is to get the covariance between $\tilde{x} \mid (\tilde{y}=y)$ and $\tilde{x}$.

I tried to deduct it as following but I am stuck:

\begin{align}
& \operatorname{cov}(\tilde{x}\mid(\tilde{y}=y),\tilde{x})=E((\tilde{x} \mid (\tilde{y} = y) \times \tilde{x})-E(\tilde{x} \mid (\tilde{y} = y) E(\tilde{x}) \\[10pt]
= {} & E(\tilde{x}\mid (\tilde{y}=y)\times \tilde{x})-\mu_1\mu_2=\text{ ?}
\end{align}

Comment: If the conditional distribution of $\bar x$ given $\bar y = y$ does not depend on $y$, then $\bar x$ and $\bar y$ are independent. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy It does. $\mu_2$ and $\sigma_2^2$ are both functions of $\tilde{y}$'s mean and variance.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  You want $\operatorname{cov}(\bar x\mid(\bar y=yu),\bar x)$.  What is that?  There is such a thing as a conditional covariance, but your condition seems to apply to only one of the two arguments to the covariance. And one of them is called "$\bar x\mid(\bar y=y)$.  What does that mean? In a notation such as $X\mid Y\sim N(\bullet,\bullet)$, there is no object called $X\mid Y$, but confused students sometimes read it that way.  Rather, there is a conditional distribution given $Y$, of $X$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Likewise $\operatorname{E}(X\mid Y)$ is the conditional expected value given $Y$, of $X$. The notation $\operatorname{E}(X\mid Y)$ does not refer to any object called $X\mid Y$.  ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: The expression $\bar x\mid (\bar y=y)\sim N(\mu_2,\sigma^2)$ means that the conditional distribution, given the event $\bar y=y$, of $\bar x$, does not depend on $y$ unless $\mu_2$ and $\sigma_2$ depend on $y$.  But the nature of that dependence is not explained here. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: QUOTE Now my question is to get the covariance between $\tilde{x} \mid (\tilde{y}=y)$ and $\tilde{x}$. END QUOTE There's no such thing as $\tilde{x}\mid(\tilde{y}=y)$. See my comment about that above. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy  $\tilde{x}$ given $\tilde{y}=y$ is a Bayesian update. Lets call it $\tilde{z}$.   $\tilde{z}$ is normally distributed and is correlated with $\tilde{x}$. Both distribution are known. What are their covariance?

Comment: I think you're confused. It makes sense to speak of the distribution of $\bar x$ given the event that $\bar y=y$, but it does not make sense to speak of a correlation between some random variable and an object called "$\bar x\mid(\bar y=y)$". There is no such object. Students sometimes see $\Pr(A\mid B)$ and think it means there is something called $A\mid B$ and that $\Pr(A\mid B)$ is the probability of the thing called $A\mid B$. That is false. Rather $\Pr(\cdot\mid B)$ means a conditional probablity measure given $B$, and the argument put into that is $A$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: You also have not explained how $\mu_2$ and $\sigma_2$ depend on $y$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy If you check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution, there is usage of $\tilde{x}|\tilde{y}=y$. I am not saying wikipedia is absolutely correct. I am writing it in this way to show you that the two random variables are correlated, as one is a bayesian update of the other.

Comment: @MichaelHardy If you calculate it yourself given what I have written, $\tilde{z}$, if you prefer this name, has a mean $\mu_2=\mu_1+\frac{\sigma^2_1}{\sigma^2_1+\sigma^2_n}y$ and variance $\frac{\sigma^2_1\sigma^2_n}{\sigma^2_1+\sigma^2_n}$. In addition, I don't think you should care how they depend on $y$, but on $x$, since I am asking the covariance of $z$ and $x$.

Comment: You are deeply deeply confused.  I did not say there was anything wrong with that usage and I did say there is a correct way to use it.  And the Wikipedia article to which you link uses it correctly in its section on conditional distributions. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Wikipedia writes that if $(X_1,X_2)$ is bivariate normal with variances both $1$ and covariance $\rho$, then $X_1\mid X_2 = x_2 \sim N(\rho x_2, 1-\rho^2)$.  That is an example of the correct usage.  One could also write $\operatorname{cov}(X_1,X_2 \mid X_3)$ if one has a joint distribution of $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$. And that means $\operatorname{cov}(\bullet\mid X_3)$ with arguments $X_1,X_2$; it does _not_ mean there is some object called $X_1,X_2\mid X_3$ or $X_2\mid X_3$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

This question says

$$\tilde{x}\sim N(\mu_1,\sigma^2_1),$$

$$\tilde{x}\mid (\tilde{y}=y) \sim N(\mu_2,\sigma^2_2).$$

This means that given the event that that $\bar y=y$, the conditional distribution of $\bar x$ is $N(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2)$.  This is a perfectly correct use of the notation $\text{“ } \tilde{x}\mid (\tilde{y}=y) \sim N(\mu_2,\sigma^2_2)\text{ ''}$.

However, the request for a covariance between $\bar x$ and something called $\text{“ }\bar x\mid (\bar y=y)\text{ ''}$ makes it appear that the poster thinks there is some random variable involved called $\bar x\mid (\bar y=y)$. The question seems to contemplate a joint distribution between that random variable and the random variable $\bar x$, so that there would be a covariance between them.  That would be the case if $y$ were a random variable, but nothing to that effect appears in the question.  That is a misunderstanding of the meaning of the notation.  The notation does not refer to something called $\text{“ }\bar x\mid (\bar y=y)\text{ ''}$  Rather, the meaning of the notation is as explained in the paragraph above.

One could speak of a random variable $\operatorname{E}(\bar x\mid \bar y)$, which would be a function of $\bar y$, and ask for the covariance between that and $\bar x$.  However, without knowing anything about the joint distribution of $\bar x$ and $\bar y$, one could not specify which distribution that is.